# concate string with href path in php

Tags: php, html

I have a file with so many href attributes. I want to modify the path, just want to add absolute path with the existing.
e.g `href="parentall_files/filelist.xml"` , just needs to be changed to `href="dir/parentall/parentall_files/filelist.xml"` throughout the file.
I have written the following:

```
 $contents = preg_replace('/<a href="(.*?)"/i', '<a href="dir\/parentall\/$"',$contents);
```

But alas! it is not changing the path.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you don't just change it with `str_replace()`

```
$contents = str_replace('href="parentall_files/','href="dir/parentall/parentall_files/', $contents);
```

Comment: Hi CodeingInsane, 
I tried this but I think some silly mistake I have done. 
first of all I am using file_get_contents("html_file_path_here");
then replacing the href attribute's path and then finally echo the content. Is it right?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working. Actually,  I made a mistake, I should replace href as well as src

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
preg_replace('/<a href="(.*?)"/', '<a href="dir\/parentall\/"',$contents)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

```
$contents= str_replace('href="','href="dir/parentall/',$contents);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `{1}` after `$` sign

```
$string = '<a href="parentall_files/filelist.xml">asdsadsad</a>';
$new = preg_replace('/<a href="(.*?)"/i', '<a href="dir/parentall/${1}', $string);
```

Output is:

```
string '<a href="dir/parentall/parentall_files/filelist.xml>asdsadsad</a>' (length=65)
```